# What is the most efficient way to add zeros to end of a number?

Tags: number-representation, big-numbers

Beside `*10^n`, is there a faster way to add thousands of zeros to end of a number?

**Updated**

Timings:

```
In[230]:= First[Timing[prime*10^100000000]]

Out[230]= 3.625

In[25]:= First[
 Timing[FromDigits[
   Join[IntegerDigits[prime], ConstantArray[0, 100000000]]]]]

Out[25]= 7.547
```

**Updated**

According to Mr.Wizard answer:

```
In[46]:= First[Timing[2213*1*^200000000]]

Out[46]= 0.015 (* The real timing on the clock is 5 seconds *)

In[45]:= First[Timing[2213*10^200000000]]

Out[45]= 5.11

In[3]:= First[Timing[ToExpression["2213*1*^200000000"]]]

Out[3]= 5.078
```

But the strange thing is that by using special `1*^` notation, the reported timing is almost zero while by clock it takes roughly the same time of `10^n`. Maybe `Timing` function doesn't take Mathematica built-in notations into account.!!

**Updated 2**

Yet The fastest method to beat native `*^10` adding zero method is by shifting, even though the improvement is very tiny.

```
In[16]:= First[Timing[1223*10^100000000]]

Out[16]= 2.625

In[17]:= First[Timing[BitShiftLeft[1223*5^100000000, 100000000]]]

Out[17]= 2.547
```

Comment: Can you provide the problem example where performance suffers from slow expanding of number by zeroes at its end?

Comment: In the Karatsuba multiplication where number = A*10^n + B and number*number = A*A*10^2n + 2A*B*10^n + B*B. n can be very large.

Comment: I think there is no way to improve this thing in Mathematica: 1) obviously, translation to/from list representation of integers makes your code slower. 2) using `Compile` also will give no effect because you use very big numbers those cannot be fitted by machine numbers. Mathematica is well suited for symbolic computations and prototyping of numerical algorithms but not for great numerical performance.

Comment: @Piotr Semenov  What improved speeds can you obtain, in any other language, when multiplying numbers in the 10^8 digit size range?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau I mean the absolute time that program takes to run. For example, I am not ok with 1.5 hours that Mathematica spends doing some stuff. So in this case I prefer writing fast C++ code that takes several seconds of time to do the same stuff. So I claimed that you have to choose more suitable environment to have great performance. Mathematica's usage is limited for applications those are to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @Piotr Semenov Sure, Mathematica is not fast at everything (although this is often overstated, in that speed degradations also go with suboptimal coding). My point, for this post, is that multiplying large integers is not one of those places where Mathematica speed is substantially less than best available.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau I totally agree with you. Mathematica is very good at multiplication of BIG numbers. I did small test. I have profiled the following Mathematica code: `With[{a = RandomInteger[{10^133, 10^345}], b = RandomInteger[{10^546, 10^865}], n = 10^6}, Timing@Do[a*b, {n}]]`. The time is about 1.076sec on the average. For the same `a` and `b` I have profiled the same stuff in PARI/GP ([link](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)) that is very fast well-known computer algebra system for number theory. Code was `gettime(); for(i=1,10^6,a*b); gettime()`. Time is about 4.4sec on the average.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My original answer is **incorrect** -- it is preserved as a record of my own hubris. :^)

Simply, as Rojo points out, the calculation is still being done with `1*^1000`, it's just being done at a different time.  One may see this by manually observing the time taken for evaluation on an idle machine, or by setting this option which will print the total time taken to evaluate a Cell of code:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluationCompletionAction -> "ShowTiming"]
```

The syntax `n*^x` is still useful when making definitions as it evaluates before the definition is made.  For example, a function defined `f1 = # * 1*^100000000 &` will be faster in use than `f2 = # * 10^100000000 &` because the huge coefficient is only calculated once, but it is still calculated.

Logically, since *Mathematica* still runs on a *binary* system, a mantissa of two does not have the overhead that a decimal one has:

```
1*^100000000;
(* Time: 2.18 seconds *)

2^332200000;
(* Time: 0.00 seconds *)
```

---

There is a simple solution to this problem and it relies on a specific input form (`*^`):

```
prime = Prime @ 813580;

First[Timing[prime*10^100000000]]

First[Timing[prime*1*^100000000]]
```

> 2.106
>
> 0.

Crucially, `1*^1000` is directly interpreted by *Mathematica* as the number 10<sup>1000</sup> while `10^1000` actually calculates this number.

---

This turns out to be anything but "simple" as I cannot think of a clean way to insert exponents programmatically into the input syntax `n*^exp` in a manner than retains its benefit.

Hardly nice, but at least as a proof of concept one could bodge this together with `$PreRead`:

```
$PreRead = # /. 
    RowBox[{"zeros", "[", exp_, "]"}] :> 
     "1*^" <> ToString@ToExpression@exp &;

prime = Prime @ 813580;
e = 100000000;

prime*zeros[e]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.0110006

```
prime*zeros[e] === prime*1*^100000000
```

> True

Comment: Your solution does the magic but how can I use it with variables like First[AbsoluteTiming[prime*1*^ e]]. It gives error

Comment: @MohsenAfshin I see your point.  I believe you would need to use `prime * ToExpression["1*^" <> IntegerString@e]`

Comment: thanks for your reply but using ToExpression causes Mathametica to calculate the result again. Timing become 2.453 again

Comment: @MohsenAfshin You're right again.  I never actually attempted that input form and I just expected that it would work, which was foolish.  Let me think about this.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin Thanks for posing an intriguing problem.  I wish I had a good solution for you, but I do not.  I added a proof-of-concept for one approach to my answer but I shall be seeking a better one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mr.Wizard you're Mathematica GURU

Comment: @MohsenAfshin thank you, but I recommend that you do not Accept this answer, not yet at least, as: (1) I hope there is a better way; (2) If there is not this hackish method should at least be made more robust.

Comment: Interesting solution, Mr.Wizard.

Comment: @Chris Thanks.  The second part clearly needs work however, and I have a couple of ideas, but first regarding your answer try this syntax:  `FromDigits[{{123}, 20}]`.  Sadly, that does not prove to be fast.

Comment: **I'm frustrated by how many things don't work**: `ToExpression`, `ImportString`, `Read` ... there must be a solution!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard in an expression like Result = A*A*zeros[2*RightLen] + 2*A*B*zeros[RightLen] + B*B; the 'zeros' sometimes doesn't work. Sometimes (in some runs) the number of zeros are not interpreted correctly

Comment: @MohsenAfshin I'm not surprised; it is a very limited replacement rule as written.  You'll also not be able to use `zeros @ x` or `x // zeros`.  As I said this will need to be made more robust if it is to actually be used.  I'm still bothered that I can't find a better way so I keep looking, rather than improving this, but if I come up empty in a day or two I'll rewrite this to be at least passably practical.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've updated the question, it seems that timing for this notation isn't reported correctly

Comment: I think the problem is that 1*^200000 also has to "do the calculation". It't just that it's done in the parsing stage before any timing function can get to report it. So, there's nothing advantagous in principle about trying to do the math while parsing, and as soon as you move the parsing inside a timing function (by using `ToExpression`) you get a reality report

Comment: @Rojo **FACEPALM** -- Oh dear, I'm afraid you're right.  Talk about embarrassing, but as always I learn from these things.  Now, what do I do with this post?

Comment: @Rojo, your note is very elegant.Thanks. But "always there's a room" for improvment

Answer (score 0):

You could try timing this method:

```
FromDigits[Join[{123}, ConstantArray[0, 20]]]
```

> 12 300 000 000 000 000 000 000

Comment: `IntegerDigits[123]` is an extra that can be easily removed. One can perform just by `FromDigits[{123}~Join~ConstantArray[0,20]]`. But I think this code is slower than just `123 * 10^n` due to translation to/from list representation of integer.

Comment: It doubles processing time

Comment: The time consuming phase is FromDigits not the joining phase.